# Show image from other domain without showing the domain name - PHP

Tags: php

I want to show an image on my website but not want to save in on my hosting.
I want to show it something like this:

```
<img src="https://example.com/img/pic.jpg">
```

or

```
<img src="https://example.com/img/image.php?img=pic.jpg">
```

Instead of:

```
<img src="https://example.org/img/pic.php">
```

I have tried using PHP `file_get_contents()` and `CURL` etc but none of that works.

This below codes have worked which convert image from URL to `data:image` but it takes too much time to load.

```
$url = 'https://otherdomain.com/img/'.$_GET['img'];
$allow = ['gif', 'jpg', 'png'];  // allowed extensions
$img = file_get_contents($url);
$url_info = pathinfo($url);

// if allowed extension
if(in_array($url_info['extension'], $allow)) {
  // Format the image to data:image :  data:{mime};base64,{img_data_base64};
  $re = 'data:image/'. $url_info['extension'] .';base64,'. base64_encode($img);
}
else $re = 'Invalid extension: '. $url_info['extension'];

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($src);  // output $re data
```

I want proper URL format as I have mentioned above(https://example.com/img/image.php?img=pic.jpg) without saving image on my server.

**NOTE:** *Here `https://example.com` is my domain but `https://example.org` is not.*

Thanks

Comment: I did not understand what exactly you are trying to do. example.com is your domain or the other one?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that. `https://example.com` is my domain but `https://example.org` is not.

Comment: I think I maybe got the answer. Trying it out just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

Your php page url - https://example.com/img.php?img=abc.png;

img.php code (You can change image path or url as per you)
think image url https://picsum.photos/id/666/536/354 as another domain https://example.org in your case

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
readfile('https://picsum.photos/id/666/536/354');
```

Comment: Thanks, This is exactly what I wanted.